# Predict values of answers

Tags: python, hyperlink, prediction

I'm trying to create a link prediction (or a score prediction) for a movie's databases.
Every user evaluated some films.
For every user, I have an array composed as follows: `[user_id, age, school, ecc]`. Every value (excepts the `"user_id"` is between `[0,5]`.
The evaluation are composed as follows: `[user_id, film_name, overall_evaluation, director_evaluation, script_evaluation, actors_evaluation, editing_evaluation, costume_evaluation, soundtrack_evaluation]`
I need to predict a user's evaluation for a specific film.
Do you know how to start?

Comment: have you considered a linear regression model

Comment: The topic is suitable more for: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ not SO.

Comment: @ipj Ok, thank you. I'll move the question in stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MZ Linear regression should have two different parameters, while I have a completely different situation where I need to first evaluate similarity between users and then find which evaluation a users would give to every feature of the film

Comment: linear regression can have ≥1 parameters, not just 2

Comment: @MZ I'll try with linear regression then
Thanks!